# What are the planets in Eä?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

In the Silmarillion The Sun and Moon are actually Maia bearing lamps, Arien and Tilion. Is there any writing on the sources of Mars, Jupiter and the other planets?